# Randomly placing polygon within delimited area in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, random, sampling, advanced-license-level

I need to compare the number of animal species in a polygon of my study site against the number of species in a polygon of the same shape and size of my study site but located randomly within a specific region.

Does someone have an idea on what tool/procedure could I use in ArcGIS 10.3.1 (full license) to do so?

Basically I just need to randomly place my study site polygon within the area of a larger region delimited by another shapefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "Create Random Points" to generate a single Point inside the Larger Region. It is inside Data Management, Sampling Toolbox. You can move your Study Area from its current Centroid to the Random Point, saving it as a new feature class.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid edge clipping issue if it intersects with the boundary?

Comment: You can Buffer the Larger region, inward, by half the width of the Study area. This would force the Random Point to be far enough from the edge so the Study Area would not touch the edge.